# Excel VBA How to Loop Through a Dataset and Skip Every Other Row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have in Excel worksheet in column A a list of employee Numbers. Each number shows up twice in the list with same name but different company. I want to loop each number in the list and compare it to another list to check in which comapny the employee works now.

for example:

```
112 Rafael ABC
112 Rafael NBS
223 Jose ACM
223 Jose NBS
345 Dave ACM
345 Dave NBS
```

I want to check Rafael's Number once and then Jose's and the Dave's. I need help with the loop itself - how to skip a row every time.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicats()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim MainWB As Workbook
Dim MainSheet As Worksheet
Dim MLRow As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim emp As Range

Set MainWB = ThisWorkbook
Set MainSheet = MainWB.Worksheets("Main")

'Here is not relevant code
.
.
.
With MainSheet
     MLRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     Set emp = .Range("A1:A" & MLRow)
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("A1:M" & MLRow).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A" & MLRow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Put values into array, loop through it `For i = 1 to UBound(vArray,1) Step 2 : Next i`

Comment: Can they only appear twice?

Comment: @QHarr yes. only twice.

Comment: Then AntiDrondert's suggestion is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know, if this is what you want and the data is exactly as you have shown.

```
With MainSheet
     MLRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     Set emp = .Range("A1:A" & MLRow)
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Range("A1:M" & MLRow).Sort key1:=Range("A2:A" & MLRow), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With
'Loop the cells and skip 1
For x = 1 To MLRow
     'Your Code
x = x + 1
Next x
```

Comment: I prefer `For x = 1 To MLRow Step 2` instead of messing with the counter within the loop, but both ways work.